# Understanding contrastive loss, math VS implementation

Tags: loss-functions

I'm working on unsupervised learning techniques and I've been reading about the contrastive loss function. Specifically in this paper [Momentum Contrast for Unsupervised Visual Representation Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.05722.pdf) they describe the loss function mathematically as:

[image: Contrastive]

However when they show the pseudo code it's as follows:

```
# f_q, f_k: encoder networks for query and key
# queue: dictionary as a queue of K keys (CxK) 
# m: momentum
# t: temperature
f_k.params = f_q.params # initialize
for x in loader: # load a minibatch x with N samples
    x_q = aug(x) # a randomly augmented version
    x_k = aug(x) # another randomly augmented version
    q = f_q.forward(x_q) # queries: NxC 
    k = f_k.forward(x_k) # keys: NxC
    k = k.detach() # no gradient to keys

    # positive logits: Nx1
    l_pos = bmm(q.view(N,1,C), k.view(N,C,1))

    # negative logits: NxK
    l_neg = mm(q.view(N,C), queue.view(C,K))

    # logits: Nx(1+K)
    logits = cat([l_pos, l_neg], dim=1)

    # contrastive loss, Eqn.(1)
    labels = zeros(N) # positives are the 0-th
    loss = CrossEntropyLoss(logits/t, labels)
```

I don't understand how math and pseudo code are related. I get that the bmm and mm function are the dot project. Also that the l_pos is the top part of the term (query and single key value) while the l_neg is the bottom (query and values from the queue). Why are those 2 values concatenated, then compared with 0s? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dug into this and I get what's going on now.

The big idea is that you can think of this just like classification. If you had K+1 categories, and a one hot of the true category, you'd want your prediction to have the true category be a large value and all the others be small.

If q and k+ vectors are close together, then the dot product (l_pos) will be large. The dot product of q and K (l_neg) will be small if they are far from each other. l_pos is our true class predicted probability and l_neg is for the other classes probabilities. So we then create a tensor by concatenating the l_pos and l_neg and give our label as the first item. CrossEntropyLoss then does the softmax and negative loss likelihood.

I further proved this to myself with an example:

```
def norm_tensor(x):
    x = np.array(x)
    x = x/np.linalg.norm(x)
    return torch.tensor(x)

t = 0.07
q = norm_tensor([[1.0, 0.01, 0.0]])
k_p = norm_tensor([[1.0, 0.02, 0.]])
k_neg = norm_tensor([[1, 1, 1]])
```

q     -> [[1.0000, 0.0100, 0.0000]]

k_p   -> [[0.9998, 0.0200, 0.0000]]

k_neg -> [[0.5774, 0.5774, 0.5774]]

```
pos = torch.mm(q, k_p.transpose(1,0))
neg = torch.mm(q, k_neg.transpose(1,0))
print(pos, neg)
```

pos -> [[1.0000]]

neg ->[[0.5831]]

```
logits = torch.cat((pos, neg), dim=1)
indexes = torch.tensor([0])
loss_func = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss_func(logits/t, indexes)
```

loss -> 0.0026

The loss is small as we expect since q and k+ are close, while q and K are farther away.